# Cypress - Behaviour of .get (to reuse obtained element)

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress with cucumber (Gherkin) and this is the Scenario:

```
Scenario: Open portfolio page
  Then I should see "Portfolio" in the header
  Then I should see a table with the following headers (1)
      | Header    |
      | Currency  |
      | Quantity  |
      | Companies |
  Then I should see a table with the following headers (2)
      | Header    |
      | Currency  |
      | Quantity  |
      | Companies |
```

Now, the first implementation (1) always pass but the second (2), the one that "reuse" the "table" object, always fails.

```js
Then('I should see a table with the following headers (1)', (dataTable) => {    
    // it calls backend to retrieve data
    cy.wait(2000) // wait 2 seconds

    cy.get('table').should('be.visible')

    for (let row of dataTable.rows()) {
        cy.get('table').find('th').should("contain", row[0])
    }
})

Then('I should see a table with the following headers (2)', (dataTable) => {    
    // it calls backend to retrieve data
    cy.wait(2000) // wait 2 seconds

    const table = cy.get('table')
    table.should('be.visible')

    for (let row of dataTable.rows()) {
        table.find('th').should("contain", row[0])
    }
})
```

It actually fails on the second header, "Quantity".

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: th, but never found it. Queried from element: [ , 3 more... ]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cypress commands *yield* their results, and do not return them](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Subject-Management). I would suggest that you re-write your test to either not require the `table` element to be *returned*, or use an alias.

```js
// Using an alias
Then('I should see a table with the following headers (2)', (dataTable) => {    
    // it calls backend to retrieve data
    cy.wait(2000) // wait 2 seconds

    cy.get('table').as('table')
    cy.get('@table').should('be.visible')

    for (let row of dataTable.rows()) {
        cy.get('@table').find('th').should("contain", row[0])
    }
})
```

```js
Then('I should see a table with the following headers (2)', (dataTable) => {    
    // it calls backend to retrieve data
    cy.wait(2000) // wait 2 seconds

    cy.get('table').should('be.visible')

    for (let row of dataTable.rows()) {
        cy.get('table').find('th').should("contain", row[0])
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

cy.get is somewhat unlike $ or document.querySelector. It yields a promise, which can't be used the way you wanted. However you query using it the same way you would using jQuery, since Cypress is jQuery wrapped in promises... So, if you want to massage elements you queried earlier, either pass them by .then() or give them alias and reuse later.